# $\forall\varepsilon > 0\exists\delta > 0:(|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon)\implies(0<|x-a| < \delta )$. $f(x)=x$ satisfies this for all $a$ and $\ell$?

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

This is to be found in the answer to problem 26 (b) of chapter 5 of Michael Spivak's Calculus 3rd edition. The problem reads as follows:

> **26** Give examples to show that the following definitions of $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\ell$ are *not* correct.
>
> **(b)** For all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$, then $0<|x-a| < \delta$.

I thought of constant functions because they do not satisfy this condition, but approach a limit "everywhere". This means, let $f(x)=c, c\in \mathbb R$ and let $a\in \mathbb R$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$, then $|f(x) - c|=0 < \varepsilon$ for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-a| < \delta$ for any $\delta > 0$ and not just some $\delta > 0$. (It is already shown in the text of this chapter that $\lim_{x\to a}c=c$.)

In his answer Spivak also mentions constant functions but then adds the following:

> Moreover, the function $f(x)=x$, for example, satisfies this condition no matter what $a$ and $\ell$ are.

What does he mean by that? It seems to me that if $|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$ holds, then $|x - \ell| < \varepsilon$ so $a=\ell$ does hold, which means it does matter what $a$ and $\ell$ are. Unfortunately, I really don't understand what he is getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If $|f(x)- l| < \varepsilon$ holds, then $|x-l|<\varepsilon$

This is true.

> so $a = l$ does hold

This is also true, but not necessary. You have assumed that $\delta$ is small (equal to $\varepsilon$), but this need not be the case. We are free to chose $\delta$ as we please, so $|a-l|$ can actually be as big as we like (using this incorrect definition).

In the true definition, we are asking "Can we find $x$ close enough to $l$ such that $|f(x) - l| < \varepsilon$". In the bad definition above, we are asking "Can we find a $\delta$ **big enough** such that if $|f(x) - l| < \varepsilon$, then $|x - a| < \delta$".

The important thing to take note of is the order which each section appears. Let's break down the 'definition' given in the question step by step to see where we go wrong.

### Step 1 - What is given?

We are trying to show that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = l$, so $a$ and $l$ are fixed.

### Step 2 - Choose an epsilon

We have been told that what follows must hold for all $\varepsilon > 0$, so we let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary but, from this point onwards, fixed.

### Step 3 - Find a delta

We want to find a $\delta$ that 'works'. By this we mean, can we find a $\delta$ such that, if |$f(x) - l| < \varepsilon$ then $|x-a| < \delta$?

Suppose that $|f(x) - l| < \varepsilon$. Then, by definition of $f$, $|x-l| < \varepsilon$, so we have $x$ being 'close' to $l$. Can we find a delta such that $|x-a| < \delta$? Sure we can! We just pick delta to be as big as we need. So, using this definition, as long as we pick $\delta$ large enough, it works for all choices of $a$ and $l$.

### Example

Let's consider the following example:

> Using this (incorrect) definition, show that $\lim_{x\to 5}f(x) = 27$, where $f(x) = x$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. We seek $\delta > 0$ such that, if $|x-27|<\varepsilon$, then $|x - 5| < \delta$.

If $|x - 27| < \varepsilon$, and $\delta > 22 + \varepsilon$, then
\begin{align*}
|x - 5| &= |x - 5 + 27 - 27| \\
 &\leq |x - 27| + |-5 + 27| \\
 &= |x - 27| + |22| \\
&< \varepsilon + 22 \\
&< \delta
\end{align*}

Hence $\lim_{x\to 5}f(x) = 27$.

Clearly, this is nonsense, but it is a good exercise in demonstrating why the order of the statements in the definition is important.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In your example, why is $\delta > 22 + \varepsilon$ and not $\delta \geq 22 + \varepsilon$?

Comment: @Carlevaro99 this is a good question! From the definition, I want to find $\delta$ such that $|x-5|<\delta$. On the fourth line of my proof, we see $|x-5|<\varepsilon + 22$, so any $\delta \geq \varepsilon + 22$ will work. I just decided to choose the strict inequality. It’s important to note that we just have to find any $\delta$ that works, not the smallest one. I could have equally chose $\delta > 100 + 22 + \varepsilon$

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**
JEdwards and fleablood already explained much of what I added. Sorry! Not trying to poach answers. I'll leave mine up in case it's useful but please don't give me points that should go elsewhere!

I've missed the main thrust of what Spivak's getting at. The bad stuff I pointed out is true, however there's a more general issue.

With $f(x)= x$, no matter what we choose for $\ell$, $a$, or $\varepsilon$, we can find *some* $x$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x) -\ell| < \varepsilon$. We just have to make $\delta$ big enough.

For example, take $a = 0$, $\ell = 10$.

Now, For any $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ ($\delta \geq 11$ works) such that $|f(x) - 10| < \varepsilon$ and $0 <|x-a|< \delta$.

But this suggests that $\lim_{x\to 0}x = 10.$

In other words, this $f$ is such that it approaches *every* number *somewhere* so using the criteria of our bad limit definition, if we make $\delta$ big enough we can show that $f(x)$ approaches any value, anywhere.

**Original Post**

> What does he mean by that? It seems to me that if $|()−\ell|<\varepsilon$ holds, then $|−\ell|<\varepsilon$ so $=\ell$ does hold, which means it does matter what $$ and $\ell$ are.

This is true, however, the bad limit condition also says that for all $x$ satisfying $|()−\ell|<\varepsilon$, that $0 < |x-a|$.

For $f(x) = x$, $\lim_{x\to a} x = a$.

For $x = a$, we have $|f(x) - \ell| = |a - a| = 0 < \varepsilon$, but, $0 \not<|x-a|< \delta$

The same thing happens for constant functions. They satisfy $|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$ at $x = \ell$, which is not allowed.

As an aside, this bad limit definition also runs into problems with functions that have the same limit at multiple different points. For example, $f(x) = x^2$ approaches $1$ at both $x = 1$ and $x = -1$.

Here we're forced to make $\delta$ big enough to cover both of them. Consequently, the $\delta$ neighborhood includes many $x$ that do not satisfy the original $\varepsilon$ condition. For cases like this, the $\delta$ neighborhoods stop being useful (even setting aside the earlier $x=a$ problem.)

**Edit:** Another point: using this definition of limits and considering constant functions, if $f(x) = c$ then then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ and all $x$, $|f(x) - c| < \varepsilon$. The fact that every $x$ satisfies this $\varepsilon$ requirement means that for the limit $c$ to exist at any point $a$, we require some $\delta > 0$ such that $|x-a|< \delta$ **for all** $x$. No such $\delta$ exists. Constant functions cannot approach limits.

Comment: Could you explain why you think OP's statement 'so $a=l$' is true please? I can't see how we can make this inference from the given (bad) definition.

Comment: I read it to mean "for the function $f(x) = x$, if we apply this bad definition to the case $\lim_{x\to a} x = a$, the conditions that come out of this are: for all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - a| < \varepsilon$, then $0<|x - a| < \delta$. OP correctly noted that $\delta = \varepsilon$ works in so far as $|x - a| < \varepsilon$, but this leaves off the $0< |x - a|$ condition, which is a problem.

Comment: Hey Ben, cool answer! "The same thing happens for constant functions. They satisfy $|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$ at $x = \ell$, which is not allowed." I think you meant to say that they satisfy $|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$ at $x = a$.

Comment: Furthermore, does your observation mean that Spivak is only partly correct and the correct given answer should be "Moreover, the function $f(x)=x$, for example, satisfies this condition no matter what $a$ and $l$ are, if $a\neq l$."?

Comment: One more thing. "For every $\varepsilon > 0$" contains also large $\varepsilon$ satisfying $\varepsilon > |\ell-a|$. With your reasoning it follows that $\lim_{x\to a} x = \ell$ is *always* false (using the wrong definition) , since there is always an $\varepsilon$ for which $x=a$ satisfies $|f(x) - \ell| < \varepsilon$. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry my answer is so muddled! I think that if we use the Bad limit definition then: 1) limits do not exist for constant functions. 2) The Identity function $f(x) = x$ satisfies the limit conditions for any $\ell \neq a$, that is, we can show $\lim_{x\to a} x= \ell$ for any $a\neq \ell$, but $\lim_{x\to a} x \neq a$.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, okay:

Consider this.  Using the weird wrong definition.

$\lim_{x\to 3} x = 591$.

Proof: For any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = 588 + \epsilon$

If $|f(x) - 591| < \epsilon$ then $|x-591| < \epsilon$ so $591 -\epsilon < x < 591 + \epsilon$.  So $588 -\epsilon < x -3 < 588+ \epsilon$.

So $-\delta = -588 - \epsilon < 588-\epsilon < x-3< 588 + \epsilon=\delta$

So $|x-3| < \delta$.

So $\lim_{x\to 3} x = 591$.